# Symfony2 + OneToMany - read from database error

Tags: symfony, orm, one-to-many

I'm trying to learn read/write data to/from database, and I have a huge problem :

My entities looks :

Kategorie:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="kategorie")
 */
class Kategorie
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $idkategorii;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    protected $nazwa;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ogloszenia", mappedBy="ogloszenia")
     */
    protected $ogloszenia;
```

Ogloszenia:
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="ogloszenia")
 */
class Ogloszenia
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id; 

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=100)
     */
    protected $tytul; 

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=120)
     */
    protected $tytul_seo; //tytul bez polskich znaków etc.

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $tresc; //tresc ogloszenia

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=50)
     */
    protected $dodal; //imie osoby ktora dodala ogloszenie

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    protected $kontakt; //nr tel lub mail

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Kategorie", inversedBy="kategoria")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="kategoria", referencedColumnName="idkategorii")
     */
    protected $kategoria;
```

Now, in my controller i'm trying to read all values :

```
 public function odczytajAction()
    {  
        $id = 1;
        $kategoria = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('FrontendOgloszeniaBundle:Kategorie')
                ->find($id);

        $ogl = $kategoria->getOgloszenia();
     foreach($ogl as $o)
     {
         print_r($o);
     }
       return new Response('test odczytu');

    }
```

And unfortunately symfony2 gives me an following error

```
 Notice: Undefined index: ogloszenia in /home/sl4sh/public_html/Projekt1/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1574
500 Internal Server Error - ErrorException
```

So, please tell me what's wrong with mine code ?

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid mappedBy annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ogloszenia", mappedBy="kategoria")
 */
protected $ogloszenia;
```

And also inverse side:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Kategorie", inversedBy="ogloszenia")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="kategoria", referencedColumnName="idkategorii")
 */
protected $kategoria;
```

Comment: so how it should look like?